# Mocking static method not working

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, mockito, powermock, easymock

The code I have written simply mocks a static method using powermock.

On running the test case, **no last call on a mock available** is thrown.

On debugging, found out it is thrown during expect statement.

Stack trace for the exception throwm :

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: no last call on a mock available
at org.easymock.EasyMock.getControlForLastCall(EasyMock.java:466)
at org.easymock.EasyMock.expect(EasyMock.java:444)
at junit.util.mock.Test.test1(Test.java:26)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
....
....
```

Test class written:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

import static org.powermock.api.easymock.PowerMock.mockStatic;
import static  org.powermock.api.support.membermodification.MemberMatcher.constructor;

import org.easymock.EasyMock;
import static org.powermock.api.support.membermodification.MemberModifier.suppress;
import static org.easymock.EasyMock.expect;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.powermock.api.easymock.PowerMock;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;
import static org.powermock.api.easymock.PowerMock.replayAll;

import Testing;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({Testing.class})
public class Test {

 @org.junit.Test
 public void test1() {
mockStatic(Testing.class);
expect(Testing.getWord()).andReturn("my Cal").anyTimes();
PowerMock.replay(Testing.class);
PowerMock.verify(Testing.class);
assertEquals(Testing.getWord(),"my Cal");
}
}
```

Class under test :

```
public class Testing {
public static String getWord() {
    return "from test";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried you code and it worked perfectly. So I'm not sure what to say. One thing that is not correct is that the `verify` should be at the end. But that's not what cause the issue.

I can give you the dependencies I used in case it was related to that.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <version>4.12</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.easymock</groupId>
  <artifactId>easymock</artifactId>
  <version>3.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
  <artifactId>powermock-core</artifactId>
  <version>1.6.6</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
  <artifactId>powermock-api-easymock</artifactId>
  <version>1.6.6</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
  <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
  <version>1.6.6</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Which version of java did you use?

Comment: Java 8. 1.8.0_102